# Difference between if (args.Length<1) and if (args.Length==0 || args ==null)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, parameter-passing

I was curious to know which one of these is better to use as I have to check it again n again in my code in c#

```
if(args.Length<1) //i use
```

vs

```
if(args.Length == 0 || args == null)
```

as an alternate.

or vs if something possible like

```
if (args.exists) // or more simple?
```

Comment: If `args` is null, both of these will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You could always write a wrapper method for whatever you need to check for. Something like `if(IsValid(args))...`

Comment: @NicoSchertler basically `NullReferenceException` was the reason I asked question. `IsValid` may not be possible though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First form suffers from possible `NullReferenceException` if `args` is null - you are not allowed to access its `Length` property.

Second form should be inverted to be correct:

```
if (args == null || args.Length == 0) ...
```

Third form is syntactically incorrect. You may be thinking of LINQ function `Any`:

```
if (args.Any()) ...
```

But then again you have to test against null first.

It is not clear to me what exactly you are testing. If you are checking whether there is something in the array then the condition should read like this:

```
if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
{
    // Free to access args[0] here
}
```

Comment: Looks like we had similar answers more or less simultaneously

Comment: Within a few seconds :)

Comment: Besides it works with inverted version , don't you think if(args?.any) would be ok?

Comment: Yes, @mybirthname is right: `if (!args?.Any() == true)` will work fine.

Comment: who is @mybirthname ?

Comment: He gave the answer with `args?.Any()`. That answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Both are problematic actually.

```
if(args.Length == 0 || args == null)
```

should actually be

```
if(args == null || args.Length == 0)
```

The first one will throw a NullReferenceException if args is null. The second one won't due to C#'s short circuit behavior (because once it sees that args is null it'll stop evaluating the expression). That bug also affects this one:

```
if(args.Length<1)
```

With that said,

```
if(args == null || args.Length == 0)
```

will behave the same as

```
if(args == null || args.Length<1)
```

but I think that the first is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If args is `string[]` you can make it one liner using. You are using [**Null-Conditional Operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) and you need to use C# 6.0

```
if(args?.Any() == true)
{
    //the code will go in this block if args != null and args has items in it.
}
```

EDIT: Like mentioned in the comments this will work for every `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Shouldn't that work for any `IEnumerable<T>`, not just `string[]`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes but I expect this is Console.Application in which the argsare string[]

Answer (score 1):

When C# is doing an `&&` check it will evaluate starting at the left and if the first condition is true, it will check the other conditions on the right. If it is false, it will not bother checking the rest. This is called "Short Circuitting".

If it is doing an `||` it will start at the left and as soon as one of the conditions is true, it will not check the rest of the conditions.

You have this code:

```
if(args.Length == 0 || args == null)
```

C# will check `args.Length` first, and guess what will happen if args is null. Exception.

If you switch them around, it will check `args == null` first, if it is true, since you are doing an `||` it will stop and not perform the next check. If it is not null then it will check the next condition and no exception will be thrown.

Therefore, keep these rules in mind and place your conditions cleverly.